# An inline formset of a model returns an error saying that the fields are required, even though they're filled

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

As mentioned, I'm trying to make a form on a model called `SellerCardDetail`.
The model has a foreign key to another model (`SellerAccount`), which in turn, has another foreign key to the base user model.

The model in question:

```py
class SellerCardDetail(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    card_name = models.TextField(default="CARDNAME")
    card_quality = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    card_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    card_image = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    card_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    card_notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    card_stock = models.IntegerField(default=1, blank=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    seller_details = models.ForeignKey(SellerAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.seller_details.user.username
```

The form:

```py
class SellerCardBase(forms.BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        if not self.has_changed():
            raise forms.ValidationError('I have no idea what went wrong, but I know this error is here')

SellerCardFormSet = inlineformset_factory(SellerAccount, SellerCardDetail, fields=('card_name', 'card_quality', 'card_price', 'card_notes', 'card_stock'), formset=SellerCardBase)
```

The view:

```py
@login_required(login_url="/account/")
def add_seller_card(request): 
    card_form = SellerCardFormSet
    user = SellerAccount.objects.get(user=request.user) # imported model
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = card_form(request.POST, instance=user)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return redirect("/")
        else:
            print(formset.non_form_errors)
            print(formset.errors) # the helpful "debug" that got me here
            formset = card_form(instance=user)
        return render(request, 'account/profile/addcard.html', {"formset": formset})
    else:
        return render(request, 'account/profile/addcard.html', {"formset": card_form(instance=user)})
```

And finally, the html:

```html
<form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{formset.management_form}}
            <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">List a card</h1>
            <fieldset>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input type="text" name="card_name" class="form-control" id="floatingInput">
                    <label for="floatingInput">Card name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input type="text" name="card_quality" class="form-control" id="floatingInput"> 
                    <label for="floatingInput">Card quality</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input type="text" name="card_price" class="form-control" id="floatingInput">
                    <label for="floatingInput">Price</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input type="text" name="card_notes" class="form-control" id="floatingInput">
                    <label for="floatingPassword">Notes</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input type="text" name="card_stock" class="form-control" id="floatingInput">
                    <label for="floatingInput">Card stock</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button class="btn btn-primary w-100 py-2" type="submit">List card</button>
            </fieldset>
</form>
```

Now, whenever I go to fill the form, I get the following errors:
`<bound method BaseFormSet.non_form_errors of <SellerCardDetailFormFormSet: bound=True valid=False total_forms=3>>` and

```py
[{'card_name': ['This field is required.'], 'card_quality': ['This field is required.'], 'card_price': ['This field is required.'], 'card_stock': ['This field is required.']},
 {'card_name': ['This field is required.'], 'card_quality': ['This field is required.'], 'card_price': ['This field is required.'], 'card_stock': ['This field is required.']}, 
{'card_name': ['This field is required.'], 'card_quality': ['This field is required.'], 'card_price': ['This field is required.'], 'card_stock': ['This field is required.']}]
```

If I were to render the formset, it gives me 3 empty forms. That's yet another mystery to me - why are there 3 empty forms?

How do I solve this? Would adding default values to every required field fix this, and even if it does, it seems like a hacky way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

**Three empty forms**

When you don't specify the queryset for a formset instance, it will use all the instances of the associated model plus `n_nunber` (where n_nunber is the number you specify `extra` argument) of extra empty instances (if you don't specify `extra` argument, the default is 1). In your case, the formset loads two existing instances of `SellerCardDetail` objects. To make sure you only have one form, set the  `queryset` argument in your formset instance to SellerCardDetail.objects.none(). This will ensure no SellerCardDetail objects are retrieved from the databases.

```
formset = SellerCardFormSet(request.POST, instance=user, queryset=SellerCardDetail.objects.none())
```

**Fields are required**

This is simply because you're not actually rendering the fields in your template. The input fields in your 'rendered' is of the HTML input tags you have manually defined, not from the formset.

When working with Django forms (formsers included), you should not define HTML input markup yourself, Django forms will take care of it for you. So, instead of what you did in your `add_card.html`, you can simply do:

```
<form method="post" >
{% csrf_token %} 
{{formset}} 
</form>
```

You should note that you don't need `formset.management_form` if you're not manually rendering formset. If you want to manually render the fields, you will need to loop through the form.

```
<form method="post">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">List a card</h1> 
    <fieldset>
    <div class="container">
    {% for form in formset %}
        {% for field in form %}
            <div class="form-floating"> 
            {{ field.label_tag }} //This will render the HTML label tag for the form field 
            {{ field }} //This will render the necessary HTML tag for the form field
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    </formset>
</form>
```